# Use two or more models as DataSource in Crystal Report

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, crystal-reports

I'm using Asp.net MVC 4, SAP Crystal Report and EF to make report by combining two models and show the datas on report. I'm able to work with one model but when I use two models and try to download the report from my web page I get this error,

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Database logon failed.

Here are my codes,

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult ExtractReport()
    {
        var getOwner = rentdb.OwnerRegs.Where(a => a.username == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();
        var getId = getOwner.serial;

        ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
        rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/AdminReport.rpt")));
        rd.SetDataSource(rentdb.FlatInfoes.Where(a => a.owner_id == getId).ToList());
        rd.SetDataSource(rentdb.BillPayChecks.Where(a => a.owner_id == getId).ToList());
        Response.Buffer = false;
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Stream stream = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);  // Error in this line.
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return File(stream, "application/pdf", "MyReports.pdf");
    }
```

My code maybe is wrong. If it is, is there another way to use multiple models as DataSource in Crystal Report?

Comment: It's been long since I don't use CR, but I suppose the problem is that you're not specifying the data source name when you call `rd.SetDataSource`. Is there any overload that allows to do so. OTOH, I think in CR you can only have one data source, unless you have a subreport. If so I think you should set the main report and the subreport's data source, which should be done in different ways. As I'vetold you it's been years since I don't work with CR, but I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, I'm also thinking about subreport. But I'm new to CR. Any chance you could guide me to setup two subreports in CR?

Comment: I've given you the hints of which I remember. I cannot give you further information. Please, review your repoert and improve your question with this information, and someone that has recently used CR will be able to help you.